# Where to get HELLO WORLD for .net with M2mQTT

Tags: c#, .net, eclipse, mqtt, mosquitto

Start working on **MQTT** with **.net** environment, as a novice stuck on some issues like failed to communicate between publisher and SUBSCRIBER. From **[eclipse.org](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/dotnet/)** I get the bellow syntax

```
// SUBSCRIBER
...

// create client instance
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse(MQTT_BROKER_ADDRESS));

// register to message received
client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
client.Connect(clientId);

// subscribe to the topic "/home/temperature" with QoS 2
client.Subscribe(new string[] { "/home/temperature" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

...


static void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
// handle message received
}

// PUBLISHER
... 

// create client instance
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse(MQTT_BROKER_ADDRESS)); 

string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
client.Connect(clientId); 

string strValue = Convert.ToString(value); 

// publish a message on "/home/temperature" topic with QoS 2
client.Publish("/home/temperature", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strValue), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE); 

...
```

In the above syntax how I get the **MQTT_BROKER_ADDRESS** ,  so far I understood from other document like [hivemq](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-m2mqtt)  I need to deploy it. Is there any broker available to use it? I need a **HELLO WORLD** type project on MQTT for .net.
Which have publisher,subscriber and broker.

Answer (score 1):

[mqtt.org](http://mqtt.org) is a good place to start for help with all things MQTT, in it's wiki section it has a collection of public facing brokers that can be used for getting started.

https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/public_brokers

Comment: hardillb,thanks for your reply, want to know why my server not response me with my client. thank you

Comment: That's not what you asked in this question

Comment: hardillb,please show me some guide line why my server gnatmq not response me.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse(MQTT_BROKER_ADDRESS));
```

with

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("broker.mqtt-dashboard.com");
```

where `broker.mqtt-dashboard.com` is the address of an MQTT broker provided by HiveMQ for testing purposes.